# A-frame color is set to a variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, aframe, virtual-reality

I am wondering how it would be possible in A-frame (aframe.io) to set the color of an object to a variable. For example, if a variable called x has a value of #8F3A84 then the color of the shape will be set to that color. If the variable has a value of #738F3A then the shape will also set to that color. How can I achieve something like this?
Here is the code for my shape:       `<a-box position="0 20 0" static-body width="20" depth="20" height="0.1"></a-box>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function instead of a variable. Like the following:

```
const changeColor = (eleId, colorValue) => {
  const box = document.getElementById(eleId)
  box.setAttribute('color', colorValue)
}
```

Edit

Full Implementation

index.html

```
<HTML>
<body>
  <a-scene stats="" inspector="" keyboard-shortcuts="" screenshot="" vr-mode-ui="" device-orientation-permission-ui="">
    <a-box id='test' position="0 5 0" static-body="" width="5" depth="5" height="5" material="" geometry=""></a-box>
  </a-scene>
</body>
<script>
window.changeColor = (eleId, colorValue) => {
  const box = document.getElementById(eleId)
  box.setAttribute('color', colorValue)
}

changeColor('test', 'red')
</script>
</html>
```

Call the changeColor function from anywhere

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply to this, I'm trying to code but I cant get it working. Is there an example of this? I've tried all the code and creating the variables but my cube is showing up as white which is the default color.

Comment: I updated my answer to have a full implementation. The only change I made from your `a-box` tag was to change the position, height, width and depth values.